# Oracle DB, Glassfish, Hibernate and character encoding

Tags: oracle, hibernate, glassfish

We have an Oracle DB using UTF-8 (NLS_CHARACTERSET = AL32UTF8).
We then have a J2EE application in Glassfish which uses Hibernate.

While using SQL Plus or SQL Developer we can read and write the data correctly but we are not able to get special characters programmatically.

Reading an `ä` we get `√§`

Looking at similar questions I tried:

- tuning Hibernate properties

  ```
  <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8" />
  ```
- adding the `defaultNChar=true` connection property in Glassfish
- adding the `defaultNChar` connection property through Hibernate

  ```
  <property name="hibernate.connection.defaultNChar" value = "true"/>
  ```
- setting the charset to `utf8`

  ```
  <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="utf8" />
  ```

But I'm still not able to get any character which is not basic ASCII.

Any hint on what am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: with get I mean fetch with a select statement. Checking with a debugger or comparing with the correct (e.g., `"ä"`) string with an assertion.

Comment: Can you define "get"? Are you not able to view the characters or are you unable to select them from the database?

Comment: @Ben: you are right: I edited the question clarifying. selecting the value and checking it programmatically or with a debugger.

Comment: @Matteo is the data in nvarchar fields?

Comment: No, varchar but I can't change the DB

Comment: OK, I just saw that the problem is not in the DB connection but in my test string to ch (I forgot the -encoding option in javac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments I realized that the question does not make sense since there actually is no problem in the DB connection. As suggested in a [meta-discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121779/how-to-deal-with-an-own-question-which-should-be-deleted-with-an-open-bounty/121780#121780) I am explaining this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the comments to the original question using NVARCAR and the following line added to the Hibernate configuration file seems to work.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.defaultNChar">true</property>
```

It did for me.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said anything about your connection url from the datasource declaration. Did you try to set the encoding on the connection url?

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDB?**useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8**

I can't test for oracle, but for mysql it solves the problem.

Comment: The encoding in the URL is MySQL specific. Oracle JDBC driver doe not allow it (URL format: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//[HOST][:PORT]/SERVICE`).